# Smart Contract Token Creation (How to set total supply?)

Tags: wallets

```
totalSupply = initialSupply  *  10  ** uint256(decimals);
```

Why can't I just put `totalSupply = initialSupply`?.

I want my address to get all of the tokens and totalSupply to be equal to 1 million.

times 10 and uint256 is just confusing.

If I really need to have that, what should `initialSupply` be set to in order to have 1 million total supply?

I'm using code from https://ethereum.org/token#the-code  (advanced version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decimals` is how many places after the decimal point you want your token to support.

For example, suppose I'm creating a token called "dollars," and I want people to be able to transfer an amount like $1.25. To support that, I'll use a `decimals` value of `2`. Because Solidity only supports integers (no decimal points), inside the contract I'll need to keep track of how many *pennies* everyone has, not actually dollars. So instead of me sending $1.25, I'll be sending 125¢.

If I want to start out with $1,000,000 in my contract, I'll need to multiply that by 100 to get the number of cents. So `initialSupply = 1,000,000`, `decimals = 2`, and thus `totalSupply = 1,000,000 * 10**2 = 1,000,000 * 100 = 100,000,000`. An `initialSupply` of $1,000,000 became a `totalSupply` of 100,000,000¢.

(`10**2` means 10 raised to the power of 2.)

If you don't want to support any digits after the decimal point, you can simply set `decimals` to `0`. Note that `10**0 == 1`, so you'll just be multiplying by `1`, and `initalSupply` and `totalSupply` will both be the same.

Comment: I've just created the token and for some reason it had total supply of 
1 with 18 zeroes following it.

So iv decided to burn 1 with 14 zeroes following it. 

Result?
https://i.gyazo.com/fe372ac50d3b94c24ed78c79bbacedaa.png

It still has 18 zeroes but this time its 9999 then 18 zeroes.

Can you explain me how much is total supply of my token

Comment: If that was unexpected to you, then this seems like a simple math mistake. It may be simpler to use smaller numbers to see the error. 1 with 4 zeroes following it is 10,000. If you then subtract 1 with 2 zeroes after it (100), the result would be 10,000 - 100 = 9,900.

Comment: Oh, sorry, just saw that you said the same number of zeroes were present in both cases. That seems unlikely. You'd have to share the code for your token (including the parameters you set) and how you burned the tokens.

Comment: (Also how you are viewing the number of tokens both before and after burning them.)

Comment: I am using Ethereum wallet to create a smart contract.
I just copy-paste the code from https://ethereum.org/token#the-code   (the complete one not minimum viable token)

I burn the token by going to admin page and selecting burn function, then i wrote amount I wanted to burn. After transaction was done, I came back to admin page and total supply looks even bigger, 18 zeroes still but 9999 in front instead of 1.

If you could just let me know what parameters I have to write to get total supply of 1 mil with code im using, that would be awesome.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. If you pass an `initialSupply` of 1 million (1000000) to the constructor, then you'll have one million coins. Note that the value of `totalSupply` will be 1000000 followed by 18 zeroes, since the value of `decimals` is 18. (As I explained above, this is so you can transfer fractions of coins. If you prefer to disallow that, just use `1` as the value for `decimals`.)